# How do I restrict enum string values in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I have type with possible value of action

```
type PersistentAction = 'park' | 'retry' | 'skip' | 'stop'
```

Then I want to define enum with actions

```
enum persistentActions {
  PARK = 'park' ,
  RETRY = 'retry', 
  SKIP = 'skip',
  STOP = 'stop',
}
```

How to restrict enum values to `PersistentAction`?
Maybe enum is wrong type for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums can store only static values.

You can use constant object instead of enums.

Please keep in mind, it works only in TS >=4.1

```js
type PersistentAction = 'park' | 'retry' | 'skip' | 'stop'

type Actions = {
   readonly [P in PersistentAction as `${uppercase P}`]:P
}

const persistentActions: Actions = {
  PARK : 'park',
  RETRY : 'retry', 
  SKIP : 'skip',
  STOP : 'stop',
} as const
```

If you can't use TS 4.1, I think next solution worth mentioning:

```js
type Actions = {
  readonly [P in PersistentAction]: P
}

const persistentActions: Actions = {
  park: 'park',
  retry: 'retry',
  skip: 'skip',
  stop: 'stop',
} as const
```

But in above case, You should lowercase your keys.

Comment: Can we reuse `PersistentAction` type to not duplicate literal strings in `persistentActions`?

Comment: @matchish sorry, did not understand. PersistentAction is already reused in `Actions` type

Comment: I mean we duplicate literal strings
https://i.imgur.com/uI3xQeZ.png

Comment: In first case these strings are in type scope, in the second case they are values. You cant use type as value