# TS How to create enum that accepts only values of certain type

Tags: typescript

The question is as follows:

I have enum

```
enum forecastEnum {
    pressure,
    humidity,
    feels_like,
}
```

which must be like this ( I mean it must be with 'numerical' default key for sake of later sorting etc; so no use of {PRESSURE: pressure...})
but I would like to limit its (enum) values only to certain type, for example type like this:

```
type weatherParams = 'humidity' | 'pressure' | 'feels_like'
```

I have made few attempts but do not have syntactically correct solution. Is there any solution at all?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html
I don't think there is any way to specify it. You just have string and number types as values in enums. What is your actual use case, though? "If you do not need exhaustiveness checks, consider using an object literal instead."

Comment: Another thing that may be surprising is `let state: forecastEnum = 123` is allowed, even though your enum values only consist of numbers from 0 to 2. However, restricting an object literal can prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via `keyof typeof X`

Like so:

```js
enum forecastEnum {
    pressure,
    humidity,
    feels_like,
}

const forecastString: keyof typeof forecastEnum = 'pressure'
```

TypeScript playground here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAZg9gJ2AYwIYGcAuBRc0DeAUFCVAA5LrphIA0xpAFpAJYAmLmAnvabMMAA26APqCWAa2D0AvoULI4ILLEQoMmAFxQpXODCjcywfaqRosuSFAC8UAOQVgVGsHtA

Further:

You can get `"pressure"` converted to 0 by doing `forecastEnum['pressure']`

Comment: That is not what I am looking for; i need something like this (what is obvoiusly erraneous: 
```
enum forecastEnum: weatherParams { pressure,
    humidity,
    feels_like,}
``` The condition must be on members of forecastEnum.

Comment: That does nothing to progress my understanding of the question, and only makes me believe my answer is correct as per what you are asking but perhaps not what you want to ask.

Comment: @Kiszuriwalilibori to confirm, the example you put in your comment there is just an enum. Are you looking to assert property key names are typed to an enum, etc?

Comment: The enum items which are now just  any strings should be restricted/narrowed to certain strings (and weatherParams is a type which  defines the restrictions)

Comment: @N.J.Dawson I think the OP is asking whether it's possible to type-restrict the values of the enums. Usually you can add any string or numerical value to an enum, and the TS compiler will not complain about it. I'm not sure why anybody would like to restrict their own enums, though.

Comment: @qrsngky You are right with my expectations

Comment: thanks @qrsngky, I understand now and can only echo what you've said. similar questions which I think OP's already seen such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64709580/how-do-i-restrict-enum-string-values-in-typescript exist but no answer. It doesn't look like you can do much with enum in terms of manipulation either

Comment: @qrsngky The reason behind the question  is that though it is my won enum and its structure must be like that for sorting issues etc, I would like also to restrict its values in order to not add accidentally string - because in fact it is string - which is not allowed for any reasons. Yes, I know the answer does not add a lot.

Comment: @Kiszuriwalilibori One of the reasons it's hard to limit to numeric value only, is that you can use `forecastEnum[0]` to get `'pressure'` and `forecastEnum[1]` to get `'humidity'`, so the values always includes strings.
You can check that `let test: Record<any, number > = forecastEnum` fails but `let test: Record<any, string|number> = forecastEnum` succeeds.